# What study has shown that "about two thirds of acquisitions end up destroying shareholder value"?

Tags: equities, research

[The Best of Value Investing - Part 1](https://youtu.be/jGlvLXE82ug?t=34m45s) says:

> Study show [sic] that about two thirds of acquisitions end up destroying shareholder value.

What study has shown that?